# Multiple table joins in Spring Data JPA (Spring Boot 2)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am fairly new to Spring Boot. I am trying to join a bunch of tables and get some data back. I have created the entities and repositories for the three tables I am working with. The query I am working with joins all three tables. My first question is

1. Since the query joins all three tables, which repository class should I keep this method in?
2. The query has NOLOCK. Does the JQL support it?
3. The three entities I have are Employee.java, EmployeePosition.java and EmployeeAction.java.

Below is the SQL Query (native query) that I am working with. Can it be converted to Spring Data JPA query language from the native query?

```
SELECT
           A.EMPL_ID
         , A.HIRE_DT
FROM
           HR.EMPLOYEE A WITH(NOLOCK)
           INNER JOIN
                      HR.EMPLOYEE_POS B WITH(NOLOCK)
                      ON
                                 A.SEQ_NO = B.SEQ_NO
           INNER JOIN
                      HR.EMPLOYEE_ACN C WITH(NOLOCK)
                      ON
                                 A.SEQ_NO = C.SEQ_NO
WHERE
           A.EMPLOYEE_STATUS in ('ACTIVE')
           AND B.JOB_GRP='IT'
           AND C.ACN IN ('HIRE')
ORDER BY
           A.HIRE_DT ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend to use `@Query` or @`Native Query` to solve this type of problem in Spring Data JPA.

Just to shed some light on your questions,

1. You should create a Spring Data JPA repository of `Employee`. But the other two are still `Entity`. Repositories basically represent a collection of aggregate roots, which in turn are some of your entities, that you'll access and which enforce business constraints on others. Eg., You have `Employee` consisting of `EmployeePosition`, the `Employee` be the aggregate root as it controls the lifecycle of the `EmployeePosition` etc. Hence you'd define a repository for the Employee but not for the `EmployeePosition`. So it's by far not all entities that you'd create repositories for.
2. You can use `@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)`. But its at the transaction level. Using `@NativeQuery` is safer to this type of stuff as its at database level.
3. Since you have all the relationships defined at `Entity` so now you can directly use [JPA Query Methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) to fetch the data. You can use [Derived Query](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions) to do so. Something along the lines of

`List<Employee> findByEmployeePositionAndEmployeeActionAndStatus(EmployeePosition position, EmployeeAction action, String status)`